# Text mode IRC client that can trigger a command on an event

Tags: linux, irc

I'm a bit of an IRC addict, and I tend to appear online most of the time because I use a bouncer. I would like to get notifications to my phone when I'm mentioned on IRC. I *don't* want to run an IRC client on the phone for all of this. I can use pushbullet or any number of notification services for the notification part - I need an IRC client that

- works with znc in multiserver mode(so, it should be able to join the same server, with the same username with different passwords)
- relatively easily be scripted to send trigger a command to send me a message - ideally when my username is mentioned, and if there's a disconnection from the system I run znc on to an IRC server its connected. I need to be able to send the message in question as an argument for the command as well.

  I'll be using https://github.com/Azelphur/pyPushBullet to send a note, and everything but the note contents will be static. I would want something like "Message on %networkname% %channel%, from %username% : %message_contents%" for message notifications, "bouncer has disconnected from %network%" and so on for the message contents
- CLI based so I can run it in screen
- runs on linux - I run Ubuntu 12.04 LTS so it absolutely needs to work on what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily achieved using ZNC itself. Since you intend to use pyPushBullet, take a look at ZNC's [modpython](http://wiki.znc.in/Modpython).

Sample module:

```
import znc

class MyNotifier(znc.Module):
  def OnChanMsg(self, nick, channel, message):
    if "JourneymanGeek" in message.s:
      # Push!
```